# Xamarin Forms Navigation page searchbar entries unable to write

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have two pages MainPage and SecondPage1 .in App.xaml.cs I Navigate to Secondpage1 using this code:
App.xaml.cs :

```
//MainPage = new  Fmkt44Application.MainPage();/*First Approach*/
  MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());/*Second approach*/
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
// App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new SecondPage1());/*First Approach*/
await Navigation.PushAsync(new SecondPage1());/*Second approach*/
```

Problem is if I use  both approaches I can navigate to secondpage1 but if I use second approach I cant write on searchbar or any entries. What is the reason and how can I Fix it?

Here is MainPage.xaml.cs

```
namespace Fmkt44Application
{
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
 {
  public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task LoginControlAsync(Object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        User.UserName = entry_user.Text;
        User.Password = entry_passw.Text;
        if (User.CheckUserInformation() == false)
        {
            DisplayAlert("Login", "Kullanıcı Adını veya şifresini giriniz", "OK");
        }
        else
        {
            String val = entry_user.Text + "$" + entry_passw.Text;
            CallIasWebService.Login();
            String rval = CallIasWebService.CallIASService("PROFILECONTROL", val);
            CallIasWebService.Logout();
            User.Profile = rval.ToString();

            if (rval != "0"  )
            {
                if (User.Profile != "" && User.Profile != null)
                {

                    // App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new SecondPage1());if I Call Like this I can write on Secondpage1 (First approach)
                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new SecondPage1());/*I cannot reach SecondPage1 controls/* (second approach)*/
                }
                    else
                {
                    DisplayAlert("Login", "Kayıt yapma yetkiniz yoktur.", "OK");
                }

            }
            else
            {
                DisplayAlert("Login", "Kullanıcı Adını veya şifresi hatalıdır.", "OK");

            }
        }

    }
    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task scanncontrolAsync(Object sender, EventArgs E)
    {
      // await Navigation.PushAsync(new SecondPage1());
        App.Current.MainPage = new SecondPage1();
    }
}
```

}

App.cs is

```
    public App ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //MainPage = new  Fmkt44Application.MainPage();(First apploach)
         MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());/*second approach*/

    }
```

Secondpage1.xaml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Fmkt44Application.SecondPage1">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <SearchBar Placeholder="Ara..." TextChanged="TextChange" x:Name="searchbar" />
        <ListView x:Name="Materials" ItemTapped="MakineSec" HasUnevenRows="True">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  >
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Material}"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Stext}"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                                <Entry Text="{Binding SerialNumber}" />
                            </StackLayout>
                            <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                                <MenuItem Text="Seç" Clicked="MakineSec" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                            </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
     </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: What does "I cannot write to my searchbar or any entries" mean?  Please include the relevant code that does not work.  And please clearly indicate the context - you would normally access controls that exist on SecondPage from SecondPage's code behind.  Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: I cannot reach the controls . But when I use same code structure without Navigationpage ı can reach. And this reason I dont know which code part relevant

Comment: Cannot reach them from where?  What specific class are you trying to reach them from?  Please provide a concrete example.

Comment: when you say "cannot reach secondpage controls" you should NOT try to directly access controls on SecondPage from MainPage.  This is just bad design.  If you want to pass values to SecondPage, use the constructor or create public properties on SecondPage that you set before navigating to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem comes from Android Emulator. I tried a real tablet problem solved.